# Sage 50 ODBC using PHP-SQL state IM002

Tags: php, mysql, database, odbc, sage-line-50

I'm trying to set up an ODBC connection to connect to Sage. The DSN is set up and works via Access and Excel. However using the PHP code below,

I get "SQL state IM002" or "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

```
$odbc['dsn'] = "SageLine50v19";
$odbc['user'] = "Peachtree";
$odbc['pass'] = "XXXXX";
$mysql['host'] = "localhost";
$mysql['user'] = "root";
$mysql['pass'] = "";
$mysql['dbname'] = "sagetest";
$mysql['idfield'] = "id";
$debug=true;
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should reading the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) The dsn parameter is more complex that the one you use as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleteing the USER data source name and define it as a SYSTEM data source name.

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools ->Data Sources (ODBC):
- User DSN : delete the specified User DSN
- System DSN : create a new System DSN